# Is there a standard way to typeset centered side-by-side text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

I've recently found myself writing documents with "centered side-by-side text. My solution to this problem uses the `align` environment. For example, the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Two great bands are
\begin{align*}
  \textnormal{Led Zeppelin} && \textnormal{Pink Floyd}
\end{align*}
The members of the Beatles were
\begin{align*}
  \textnormal{John Lennon} && \textnormal{Paul McCartney} && \textnormal{Ringo Starr} && \textnormal{George Harrison}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Is there a simpler way to do this?

I'm currently working with the `beamer` class, but a universal solution would be best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that `center` adds `\hfil` glue at either side:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{showframe} % for debugging

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\gcenter}{m}
 {
  \begin{center}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { & } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \hfil }
  \end{center}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Two great bands are
\gcenter{Led Zeppelin & Pink Floyd}
The members of the Beatles were
\gcenter{John Lennon & Paul McCartney & Ringo Starr & George Harrison}
More text here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more work is needed if several lines are needed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\gcenter}{m}
 {
  \begin{center}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \hfil }
    \\
   }
  \end{center}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Two great bands are
\gcenter{Led Zeppelin & Pink Floyd}
The members of the Beatles were
\gcenter{John Lennon & Paul McCartney & Ringo Starr & George Harrison}
Here are two lines
\gcenter{
  Led Zeppelin & Pink Floyd \\
  John Lennon & Paul McCartney & Ringo Starr & George Harrison
}
More text here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty cool!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you produce your image files?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I do a screen shot on a Retina display; the resulting PNG file is normally quite good.